# glmer model failed to converge but converge_ok says TRUE yet is.singular says FALSE; can I trust my model summary?

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, convergence

I'm comparing a series of models using `glmer` in `lme4`:

```
M1 <- glmer(DV ~ IV + (1|ID) + (1|Item), data=, family=binomial)
```

but when I get to the last model, with an interaction, it fails to converge, giving me the warning:

```
Warning messages:
1: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.0264424 (tol = 0.001, component 1)
2: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model is nearly unidentifiable: very large eigenvalue
 - Rescale variables?;Model is nearly unidentifiable: large eigenvalue ratio
 - Rescale variables?
```

I've tried re-scaling, that doesn't get rid of the error. I used the `converge_ok` function from package `sjstats` and it says `TRUE`.

1. does this mean I can ignore the convergence warning and trust my results?
2. Do I also need to check `is_singular` function? The result of that function is `FALSE`, but it seems like according to [this post](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sjstats/versions/0.17.3/topics/converge_ok) I would want it to be `TRUE`. So, do I need to even check this and what do I do when `converge_ok` says `TRUE` but `is.singular` says `FALSE`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the docs are a bit misleading here, which I probably need to fix. I revised the vignette, which you might refer to instead of the docs: https://strengejacke.github.io/sjstats/articles/mixedmodels-statistics.html

`converge_ok()` simply uses a different, more tolerant way, to check the model convergence. The authors of lme4 stated somewhere that convergence warnings may be false negatives, because they have very strict tests. I think there's no "one" exact threshold.

If your model is not singular, and you have no hints for severe convergence problems, your model fit should be ok.

Edit: You may also look at the [GLMM-FAQ](http://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#troubleshooting):